# Is there a way to optimize this using indexes?

Tags: postgresql, index

I'm just now learning indexes, and I was wondering if it's possible to optimize this code using them. Currently this code runs in 1.4 seconds.

```
SELECT
    C.yearID as year,
    name as teamName,
    C.lgID as league,
    D.cnt as totalBatters,
    C.cnt as aboveAverageBatters
FROM
    (SELECT 
        count(masterID) as cnt, A.yearID, A.teamID, A.lgID
    FROM
        (select 
        masterID,
            teamID,
            yearID,
            lgID,
            sum(AB),
            sum(H),
            sum(H) / sum(AB) as avg
    FROM
        batting
    GROUP BY teamID , yearID , lgID, masterid
    HAVING sum(AB) <> 0) B, (select 
        teamID,
            yearID,
            lgID,
            sum(AB),
            sum(H),
            sum(H) / sum(AB) as avg
    FROM
        batting
    WHERE ab is not null
    GROUP BY teamID , yearID , lgID
    HAVING sum(AB) <> 0) A
    WHERE
        A.avg >= B.avg AND A.teamID = B.teamID
            AND A.yearID = B.yearID
            AND A.lgID = B.lgID
    GROUP BY A.teamID , A.yearID , A.lgID) C,
    (SELECT 
        count(masterID) as cnt, yearID, teamID, lgID
    FROM
        batting
    GROUP BY yearID , teamID , lgID) D, 
    teams
WHERE
    C.cnt / D.cnt >= 0.75
        AND C.yearID = D.yearID
        AND C.teamID = D.teamID
        AND C.lgID = D.lgID
        AND teams.yearID = C.yearID
        AND teams.lgID = C.lgID
        AND teams.teamID = C.teamID
```

I've tried creating indexes for `teamid`, `yearid`, `lgid`, and `ab`, but performance is the same.

Please help!

Comment: Please check the following and add the missing information: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions  The most important parts are the table and index definitions, and the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`  Also, we know how much time it needs now, but how much do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Generally indexes will stop working when you run "top" select over a nested select, like:

```
(select 
        teamID,
            yearID,
            lgID,
            sum(AB),
            sum(H),
            sum(H) / sum(AB) as avg
    FROM
        batting
    WHERE ab is not null
    GROUP BY teamID , yearID , lgID
    HAVING sum(AB) <> 0) A
    WHERE
        A.avg >= B.avg AND A.teamID = B.teamID
            AND A.yearID = B.yearID
            AND A.lgID = B.lgID
    GROUP BY A.teamID , A.yearID , A.lgID) C
```

OR

```
   (SELECT 
        count(masterID) as cnt, yearID, teamID, lgID
   FROM
        batting
   GROUP BY yearID , teamID , lgID) D
```

You define derived tables C (as well as D etc.). Also your derived tables have GROUP and FUNCTION inside.

When you make the comparison:

```
WHERE
    C.cnt / D.cnt >= 0.75
        AND C.yearID = D.yearID
        AND C.teamID = D.teamID
        AND C.lgID = D.lgID
        AND teams.yearID = C.yearID
        AND teams.lgID = C.lgID
        AND teams.teamID = C.teamID
```

it runs over new "tables" and these new tables do not have indexes.

Comment: And then what is the way out?

Comment: depend - why is it? if it part of hard but rare report and speed on real data same - leave it. If it part of report, but on real data speed unreasonable - split, use temporary tables with indexes for example (it will be much faster). If this often used construction and must run very fast - re-design query for start use indexes. Design query based on one level of big tables.

Always any answer start from question - what we are do?